# How to do a group by on a count in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

If I have a table called Data with the following rows:

```
UserID  action
1       went shopping
1       went shopping
2       cut grass
3       work
3       work
```

I'm simply trying to create a bar chart that tells me how many actions each user took. When I select the bar chart and select the table's `UserID` column its counting basically the total row count and not the occurrences.

I'm looking for something like

```
1  2
2  1
3  2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add UserId to the axis too:

[image]

You will get:

[image]

However, I will strongly recommend you to learn DAX language, and instead of dropping UserID into a value area directly, write a **measure** and then use it. For example, create a measure:

```
User Action Count = COUNTROWS(Data)
```

and drop it into the values area.

More generally, read a good book on Power BI before jumping into it - it's not as simple as it seems.